# are iterators static pointers?

Tags: c++, iterator

One simple use of an iterator, is like this:

```
vector<int> v;
vector<int>::iterator iter;

v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(2);
v.push_back(3);

for (iter = v.begin(); iter != v.end(); iter++)
  cout << (*iter) << endl;
```

I have two questions:

1) Every time we see a declaration like `class-name::member-name` it's a static member of that class.
So, since iterators are declared as `container<type>::iterator`, can we consider they are static members of the container ?

2) Since iterators are dereferenced with the same sintax of pointers `cout << (*iter) << endl;`, can we consider that they are pointers too ?

Thank you

Comment: `v.std::vector<int>::push_back(1);`, `v.vector<int>::push_back(1);` or `v.vector::push_back(1);` being valid also disproves your first assertion.

Comment: "Static" doesn't make sense for type members.

Comment: `class-name::member-name` can refer to a nested type, which is what it does in the case of `vector<int>::iterator`. If `vector<int>::iterator` was a static data member, `vector<int>::iterator iter;` wouldn't make any sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. Every time we see a declaration like `class-name::member-name` it's a static member of that class. So, since iterators are declared as `container<type>::iterator`, can we consider they are static members of the container ?

No! The context you mention provides an inner type declaration with a class. That has nothing to do with `static` class members.

> 2. Since iterators are dereferenced with the same sintax of pointers `cout << (*iter) << endl;`, can we consider that they are pointers too ?

No. You cannot consider `iterator`s being pointers. That's just one way of a viable implementation for certain constraints specified by [iterator traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator).

Answer (score 3):

From the C++ Standard (9.2 Class member)

> 1 The member-speciﬁcation in a class deﬁnition declares the full set
>   of members of the class; no member can be added elsewhere. Members of
>   a class are data members, member functions (9.3), **nested types**,
>   and enumerators.

In this declaration

```
vector<int>::iterator iter;
```

there is declared object `iter` that has type  `vector<int>::iterator` and `iterator` in this type speifier is a **nested type** of the class `vector<int>`

Iterators are classified by their categories, Random access iterators behave like pointers because you may use the same constructions with them as like with pointers as for example you can use the operator [] or you can subtract two iterators or add an integer to an iterator.

However it does not mean that a random access iterator is a pointer though it behaves like a pointer. Pointers themselves can be considered like random access iterators.

Answer (score 2):

> 1) Every time we see a declaration like class-name::member-name it's a static member of that class.

This predicate is incorrect. You are restricting the use of the scope resolution operator to static members alone. While it is true that `class-name::` *can* be used to refer to static members, it is not always so. Helps to look under the hood and understand the difference.

For example, here:

```
class Employee{
public:
   static int objCount; 
   //other members
};
int Employee::objCount = 0;
```

the scope resolution operator does indeed refer to a static member.

However, here:

```
class outside
{
public:
      int x;
      class inside
      {
      public:
            int x;
            static int y; 
            int foo();

      };
};
int outside::inside::y = 5; 

int main(){
    outside A;
    outside::inside B;
}
```

the same operator is used to explicitly declare an object of type `inside`in `main()`. This is the case with `vector<int>::iterator`, where `iterator` corresponds to the nested class`inside`. Also, in this statement: `int outside::inside::y = 5;`, the same operator is used in both contexts.

> 2) Since iterators are dereferenced with the same sintax of pointers cout << (*iter) << endl;, can we consider that they are pointers too ?

Kind of. An iterator is a distant cousin to a regular C++ pointer, in that it is designed to act like a pointer (i.e., supports dereferencing, pointer arithmetic with random access iterators), but isn't a *real* pointer. What this means is that a pointer always points to a specific object in memory, but an iterator doesn't necessarily do so. Check [this SO post that discusses this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661053/isnt-an-iterator-in-c-a-kind-of-a-pointer).